# How to load Scala dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using IntelliJ. And I am trying to add sext dependency https://github.com/nikita-volkov/sext to my project. I have added line

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nikita-volkov" % "sext" % "0.2.4"
```

in plugins.sbt file of my project. The question is - what command should I execute to load this dependency in my filesystem, so that this dependency appears in the External libraries tree in the Scala Project Explorer. And the main thing, to remove the compilation error:

```
not found: object sext
import sext._
```

I know that Java projects have Maven pom.xml and I can add depedencies in pom.xml and execute mvn package and it loads the packages from the repository. So - I am seeking the similar command for sbt.

Comment: This should just work, but instead of `plugins.sbt`, put it in `build.sbt`. The other file describes the dependencies for your build script, not for your "real" code.

Comment: Yes, moving entry to build.sbt solved my issue. IntelliJ automatically loaded the package, but sbt update seems to do the update from the command line if executed from the root directory of the project.

Comment: `sbt` is usually run from the root directory of the project, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("io.circe" %% "circe-core"% "3.9.0")
```